# Conditions for upper-triangular factor in QR factorization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, gram-schmidt

Let $A,Q_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{m_1 \times n}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m_2 \times n}$ $Q_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{(m_1+m_2) \times n}$, and $Q_3 \in \mathbb{R}^{ (n+m_2) \times n }$ with $Q_i$ having orthonormal columns for $i=1,2,3$. Let $R_1,R_2,R_3 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be upper triangular. Assume

\begin{equation*}
A = Q_1R_1 \\
\begin{bmatrix}
B \\
A
\end{bmatrix} = Q_2R_2 \\
\begin{bmatrix}
B \\
R_1
\end{bmatrix} = Q_3R_3
\end{equation*}

Under certain conditions, $R_2 = R_3$. What are these conditions? As a side note, the problem is sort of saying that the "upper-triangular factor obtained  in $QR$ factorization when augmenting the matrix B is invariant under the unitary transformation $Q_1^{T}$."

Note that it is implicit that $m_1,m_2 \geq n$ given that $Q_i$ have orthonormal columns. The only thing I can think to try is to multiply the equations by $Q_2^{T},Q_3^{T}$ respectively and see under what constraints that makes $R_2 = R_3$. I tried expanding $Q_i$ as block matrix...this didn't lead me anywhere (but might work). I'm unsure how to exploit that $R_i$ are upper triangular.

Comment: What are the dimensions of $B$?

Comment: Sorry about that, I've edited it...$B \in \mathbb{R}^{m_2 \times n}$ and also there was a mistake...$Q_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{(m_1+m_2) \times n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I$ be the $m_2 \times m_2$ identity.  Then the matrix
$$
Q_0:= \begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 \\
0 & Q_1
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{(m_1 + m_2) \times (m_2 \times n)}
$$
has orthonormal columns.  (For why, think about $Q_0$ in terms of its indiviual columns and how the 2-norm is calculated.)

Furthermore,
$$
Q_0 Q_3 R_3
=
Q_0
\begin{bmatrix}
B \\
R_1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
B \\
Q_1 R_1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
B \\
A
\end{bmatrix}
= Q_2 R_2
$$
Since each $Q_i$ has full rank ($Q_0$ by construction; the others by assumption), then $R_3 = R_2$ follows from requring that $Q_0 Q_3 = Q_2$.

Comment: Great answer. Is there more going in the construction of $Q_0$ other than "it's just a trick with the block matrices" or is that essentially all? Also, the dimensions of $Q_0$ are $\mathbb{R}^{(m_1+m_2) \times (n+m_2)}$, correct?

Comment: Fixed the dimensions on $Q_0$.
Note that this is not an "if and only if" statement-- you asked for some conditions that imply that $R_2 = R_3$.  But I think these conditions are quite natural.  You're concatenating $B$ with $A$ and again with a piece of $A$ and then asking how they are related.  They must of course be related by the other piece of $A$-- $Q_1$-- and the trick with the block matrices gives you precisely that.  It may also help to consider why $Q_0$ is orthonormal in the first place. ;)